# docker не видит переменные из config.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

docker не видит переменные из config.js
Почему так?

Dockerfile

```js
FROM node:10 AS cps-build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

ARG NODE_ENV=production

ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

RUN cd backend && npm install --production

RUN cd frontend && npm install --production && npm run build

CMD ["node","./backend/server.js"]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

package.json backend
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я бы посоветовал включить Dockerfile в вопрос как код

Comment: @S.H. Спасибо, включил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть `/usr/src/app/backend/config`, а не находит `/usr/src/app/config`, т. к.
`WORKDIR /usr/src/app`.

Попробуйте задать WORKDIR еще раз под конец:

```
...
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/backend
CMD ["node","./server.js"]
```

Comment: помогите пожалуйста  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#